# MDL not updating two ng-repeats' checkboxes values

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, material-design-lite

I'm trying to display two ng-repeats showing the same array in two different formats: A simple list with checkboxes and the same list, with extended info and checkboxes.

The following example works fine in Angular.

```
<label ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">
  {{item.name}}
</label>

<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
  <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
  <p>{{item.desc}}</p>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">
</div>
```

But if I use Material Design Lite, the checked state isn't updated, so when you click in one checkbox, the other one stills the same.

Real example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
  <div class="mdl-card__title" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{item.photo}})'}">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{item.name}}</h2>
  </div>
  <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-{{$id}}">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change="vm.updateMDL()" class="mdl-checkbox__input" id="checkbox-{{$id}}">
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Select {{item.name}}</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

And in the list:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
  <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-list-{{$id}}">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" class="mdl-checkbox__input" id="checkbox-list-{{$id}}">
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">{{item.name}}</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

If I click one checkbox then the same one in the list, object's selected status gets toggled and the clicked checkbox doesn't change (since it didn't change to selected in the first place)

Anyone else facing this issue? Workarounds?

Comment: please show the coding, that's not working. It is not easy to guess what your problem is.

Comment: provide your MDL code so we can see what's wrong

Comment: Checkboxes also do not cause siblings to update. Only radios do that by default.